# Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

```
"ORG;WORK;X-EDIT=0;CHARSET=utf-8:ICICI Bank Limited;Salary Accounts Group;Relationship Manager";
```

Above is the string. How to retrieve "Salary Accounts Group"?

```
Regex.Match(result, "([^;]*)([^;]*)([^;]*)([^;]*)([^;]*)");
```

Comment: Are you trying to get that value by position? If so, why not use: `result.Split(';')[4]`?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the best solution is to carry out `split` and then access to the field you want. As stated by [xiaoy312](https://stackoverflow.com/users/561113/xiaoy312), you can use:

```
result.Split(';')[4]
```

However, If you still want (or need) to use a regex, then you can use a regex like this:

```
(?:[^;]+;){4}([^;]+)
or
(?:.*?;){4}([^;]+)
or
.*;(.*?);.*$
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/agcYkR/1)**

And grab the content from the capturing group